Do ants and termites form standoff lineups?
Someone sent me this video. It has a description:

A Termine line (top) and an Ant line (bottom), each protected by its column of soldiers who face each other without attacking.

Here is a screenshot from the video:

Has this behaviour been studied/verified within a scientific context?

Doesn't look peaceful to me - looks like a military stand-off.

@bob1 Agreed! Changed the wording in the title thanks to your feedback.
